# WebClient failing on physical device and emulator

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, post, oauth, webclient

> UPDATE:
>
> Maybe it's just me not understanding how oAuth works? I tried running
>   the query manually on http://www.apikitchen.com and I get a 400 error
>   there too! Just to be sure, am I constructing the URL correctly here?
>
> POST URL:
>
> https://api.bufferapp.com/1/oauth2/token.json?client_id=[hidden]&client_secret=[hidden]&redirect_uri=http://apps.joel-murphy.com/buffer/code/success.php&code=[the
>   access code I get from buffer starting with
>   1/]&grant_type=authorization_code

Original post:

I'm building a Windows Phone application which requires the use of data from a website. The website uses oAuth to authenticate users.

I used the built in web browser control to make a GET request to authenticate users. The official documentation requires the URL structure to be like this:

> GET https://bufferapp.com/oauth2/authorize?
>       client_id=...&
>       redirect_uri=...&
>       response_type=code

This part of my app works. Although when it comes to exchanging the Authorization token for an access token from the server, I am facing problems. The official documentation requires the URL structure to be like this:

> POST https://api.bufferapp.com/1/oauth2/token.json?
>        client_id=...&
>        client_secret=...&
>        redirect_uri=...&
>        code=...&
>        grant_type=authorization_code

Correct me if I'm wrong, but from what I know there is no way to make a POST request from a browser, unless submitting a form. For this reason, I have decided to use the `WebClient` class to submit data to the server. However, no matter if I run my code on an actual device or on the Visual studio emulator I always receive the following error:

> The remote server returned an error: NotFound

[image]

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong with the following code? I've spent over 5 hours across 2 days trying to solve this error, but nothing seems to be working.

The code I'm using:

```
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_UploadStringCompleted);

    wc.UploadStringAsync(new Uri(access_token_url), "POST", GetPostParameters());


    void wc_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try 
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    string GetPostParameters()
    {
        string data = "";
        data += "client_id="+client_id + "&";
        data += "client_secret=" +client_secret + "&";
        data += "redirect_uri=" + redirect_uri+ "&";
        data += "code=" + App.AccessToken + "&";
        data += "grant_type=authorization_code";
        return data;
    }
```

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong? this is driving me crazy and it's a real shame that oauth has to be so complicated when it's such a used technology nowadays.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are a few OAuth wrappers [including this one](http://localangle.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/17743#210860) which can simplify the whole process - it might be worth using something like that to get over the signing issues

Comment: Cheers mate, I'll check it out now and report back soon :)

Comment: I added the OAuthWebRequest class to my solution, however it contains 99 errors which I have no idea how to fix :( thanks anyhow

Answer (score 0):

Can you try URL-encoding the redirect_uri variable?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried changing the code to this, but I still get exactly the same error:  data += "redirect_uri=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(redirect_uri) + "&";

Comment: I just updated the OP, do you think you could take a quick look at it?

Comment: you didn't encode your URL in the updated post. the encoded URL should be http%3A%2F%2Fapps.joel-murphy.com%2Fbuffer%2Fcode%2Fsuccess.php